# БД не стартует после установки

Tags: mysql

Во время установки *MySQL* не стартует.

[image: Ошибка]

В `hosts` сделаны записи, без которых установка проходит нормально, но установить надо именно с ними:

```
10.10.10.10 nct-testing-25
smartservice 127.0.0.1
smartservice.dlink 127.0.0.1
```

Comment: Подскажите, плиз, как быть?

Comment: да кто же его знает, как быть?! На вендовсе лучше вообще не быть!

Comment: Смотрите системные логи винды. Если повезет, найдете там подсказку или даже ответ.